# PHP function to get all matched lines from a file

Tags: php, file, search

I am trying to search multiple matched lines from a html file and return those lines.

If there is single match then it works.  But if there are multiple matches it returns nothing.

Here is the code:

```
$line = getLineFromFile("abc.html", 'http://www.abc.com/');

echo $line;

function getLineFromFile($file, $string) {
    $lines = file($file);
    foreach($lines as $lineNumber => $line) {
        if(strpos($line, $string) !== false){
            return $lines[$lineNumber];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Why isn't it returning all the matched lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you return from a function that function call stops executing. You'll need to store your results in an array and then return it.

```
function getLineFromFile($file, $string) {
    $lines = file($file);
    $matches = array();
    foreach($lines as $lineNumber => $line) {
        if(strpos($line, $string) !== false){
            $matches[] = $lines[$lineNumber];
        }
    }
    return $matches;
}
```

Just make sure you check for an empty array and not `false` when checking the results of this function.

Comment: It works great! only I had to implode that array. many thanks!